# JSon Webservice

Tags: json, jquery

I have implemented webservice and call this webservice using JSON.

But i got error like **"JSON.parse: bad control character in string literal"**

Please give me a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide an example of what your webservice is returning when you call it?

It sounds as though you've got an invalid character in the JSON string, which is preventing it from being parsed, but without more detail I can't really provide you a better answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already validate my return JSON string om JSONlint.com and it gives valid jason. even i got the same error.